# POST method in WCF Rest Serivce not working when data is passed in it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, rest

I have a wcf rest Service when i used GET method it works fine when i pass the data along with the url, But i need to use post method and when there is no data to pass in post method it works fine.. 
But when some data is added then it returns Bad Request error in IE and In mozila and chrome it just returns Error.I have post the code i used in wcf service and ajax method below.pls help

Code in Ischeduler.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Ischeduler
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetData", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetDataName", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetDataName(string Name);
}
```

scheduler.cs

```
public string GetData()
    {
        string getdata = "hgello";
        return string.Format("You entered" + getdata);
    }
public string GetDataName(string Name)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered" + Name);
    }
```

Ajax request in Schedular.aspx on button click

```
$("#btnInvoke").click(function () {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      url: "http://localhost:3125/schedulerAPI_Service/scheduler.svc/GetDataName",
                      data: '{"Name": "John"}',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      processdata: true,
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      crossdomain: true,
                      success: function (data) {
                         alert(data);
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                          alert("failed " + error);
                      }
                  });
```

Wcf Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="InstaScribeCentralConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ATLT53;Initial Catalog=InstaScribeCentral;User ID=sa;Password=bmjobmjo;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="scheduler">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Ischeduler"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: when i put  jQuery.support.cors = true; in document.ready, i get data in IE But same error in Mozilla and chrome

Answer (score 0):

Pass data like this.

```
data: { Name: "John" }
```

Change the type to `post` and remove `processdata: true` anyways there is a typo, `d` in processdata should be capital `processData`. The default value of it is true so no need to specify.

Comment: yeah i changed that too but it still gives Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the [enableWebScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675191.aspx) in your `WCF` configuration like so:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Apart from that and things mentioned by @ShankarSangoli everything looks good.

Comment: i am getting this error after setting <enableWebScript/> in config --- Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.

Comment: You have two options, either remove the `UriTemplate` parameter from the `WebInvoke` attribute or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/justinjsmith/archive/2008/02/15/enablewebscript-uritemplate-and-http-methods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you must set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to false in web.config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
```

if you set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to true, you must allow AspNetCompatibilityRequirements mode in ServiceContract.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

You must also set type to "POST".